# how can i validate username, password and other one field with fosuserbundle?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I need to validate in the login three fields so that the user can enter the application, I only need a small example of how to do it or better still where is the method that really is responsible for validating in fosuserbundle, in order to be able to overwrite it

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new validation group, override the form of FOSUser and apply in it your new validation group.

[override FOSUser form](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_forms.htm)

If your object takes advantage of validation groups, you'll need to specify which validation group(s) your form should use:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($users, array(
    'validation_groups' => array('registration'),
))->add(...);
```

If you're creating form classes (a good practice), then you'll need to add the following to the configureOptions() method:

```
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'validation_groups' => array('registration'),
        ));
    }
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/groups.html

Note that the FOSUser uses the description of validation in the XML format and you can not override the validation file, you can only create a new validation group and use in own forms